# Populate a dataframe column based on a column of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the population of a region and i want to populate a column of other dataframe with the same distribution.

The first dataframe looks like this:

```
Municipio   Population  Population5000
0   Lisboa  3184984 1291
1   Porto   2597191 1053
2   Braga   924351  375
3   Setúbal 880765  357
4   Aveiro  814456  330
5   Faro    569714  231
6   Leiria  560484  227
7   Coimbra 541166  219
8   Santarém    454947  184
9   Viseu   378784  154
10  Viana do Castelo    252952  103
11  Vila Real   214490  87
12  Castelo Branco  196989  80
13  Évora   174490  71
14  Guarda  167359  68
15  Beja    158702  64
16  Bragança    140385  57
17  Portalegre  120585  49
18  Total   12332794    5000
```

Basically, the second dataframe has 5000 rows and i want to create a column with a name corresponding to the Municipios from the first df.

My problem is that i dont know how to populate the column with same occurence distribution from the first dataframe.

The final result would be something like this:

```
Municipio
0 Porto
1 Porto
2 Lisboa
3 Évora
4 Lisboa
5 Aveiro
...
4996 Viseu
4997 Lisboa
4998 Porto
4999 Guarda
5000 Beja
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do a simple map if you do;

```
map = dict(zip(DF1['Population5000'], DF1['Municipio']))
DF2['Municipo'] = DF2['Population5000'].map(map)
```

or just change the population 5000 column name in the map (DF2) to whatever the column containing your population values is called.

Comment: No, there isnt a commom column. Basically i want to create a column with the name of the municipio multiple times equal no the number of the column "Population5000" to populate my second dataframe.

Comment: Oh right? So in your second df you have the values for "population5000" within it? if so the above edit to my answer might work, if I've understood correctly!

Comment: My first dataframe has a column with the name of the Municipio, the population in that Municipio and the population normalized to 5000. 
My second dataframe has a column name Municipio that i want to populate wiht the name of the municipio of the first dataframe. Since this second dataframe has 5000 rows, i want the column Municipio with the same number of Municipios as the first dataframe (number from column Population5000)

Comment: right if you have the normalised values just create a new dictionary for it;

mapping = {10: Lisboa, 20: Porto}

just for each normalised value apply it to the name you want and run the mapping code in the answer, it should work.

Comment: sure, if the population5000 values are in both columns you can just run the map, using the code above.

Comment: You are a genius, Thanks!
I had already tried something similar but was failing to populate my column in my second dataframe becasuse i was not using map properly. Thank you once again

Comment: The unique problem is that it only populates the column with 1 Municipio of each and not with the number of Municipios as the number is "Population5000"

Answer (score 1):

I would use a simple comprehension to build a list of size 5000 with as many elements with a town name as the value of `Population5000`, and optionally shuffle it if you want a random order:

```
lst = [m for m,n in df.loc[:len(df)-2,
                           ['Municipio', 'Population5000']].to_numpy()
       for i in range(n)]
random.shuffle(lst)
result = pd.Series(1, index=lst, name='Municipio')
```

Initialized with `random.seed(0)`, it gives:

```
Setúbal     1
Santarém    1
Lisboa      1
Setúbal     1
Aveiro      1
           ..
Santarém    1
Porto       1
Lisboa      1
Faro        1
Aveiro      1
Name: Municipio, Length: 5000, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked.
I was using to for loops to print and save in a dataframe every single name and then order them randomly

Comment: @JoaoNuno: If it solved the problem, do not forget to accept an answer to tell future readers that you no longer need help for that question

Answer (score 0):

```
map = dict(zip(municipios['Population5000'], municipios['Municipio']))
df['Municipio'] = municipios['Population5000'].map(map)
```

I tried this as suggested by Amen_90 and the column Municipio from the second dataframe it only gets populated with 1 instance of every Municipio, when i wanted to have the same value_counts as in the column "Population5000" in my first dataframe.

```
df["Municipio"].value_counts()

Beja                1
Aveiro              1
Bragança            1
Vila Real           1
Porto               1
Santarém            1
Coimbra             1
Guarda              1
Leiria              1
Castelo Branco      1
Viseu               1
Total               1
Faro                1
Portalegre          1
Braga               1
Évora               1
Setúbal             1
Viana do Castelo    1
Lisboa              1
Name: Municipio, dtype: int64
```